# ajax returns -1 in multisite sub domain

Tags: multisite, ajax

i am using the same theme for 2 language site - i didnt use a plugin but rather
created a multisite (i like it better) - but...

**i have a problem with ajax which seems to work
for main site but not for sub-domain site.**

I tried to find a solution and as far as i can gather
**it has something to do with the admin-ajax not working for sub domains.**

There is nothing wrong with the function itself but rather
the way stuff works in multi site and in particular in subdomains

**Nevertheless - here is the function:**

```
$.post(ajax_object.ajaxurl, {
    action: 'action_submit_faq',
    sendername: sendername,
    senderemail: senderemail,       
    subject: subject,       
    questiontitle: questiontitle,       
    questionbody: questionbody,
    questionbodytwo: questionbodytwo,
    nonce: nonce,       
    dvashpot: dvashpot,     
}, function(data) {
    var $response       = $(data);
    var success         = $response.filter('#success').html();
    var error           = $response.filter('#error').html();

    $('.sendFaqLoader').fadeOut();

    // HANDLE SUCCESS >>
    if(success) {
        $.bootstrapGrowl(success, {type: 'success',offset: {from: 'bottom', amount: 20},align: 'right',width: 'auto',delay: 4000,allow_dismiss: true,stackup_spacing: 10});
        $('.publishNewQuestion').find('input#faq_sendername').val('');
        $('.publishNewQuestion').find('input#faq_senderemail').val('');
        $('.publishNewQuestion').find('#faq_questiontitle').val('');
        $('.publishNewQuestion').find('#faq_questionbody').val('');
        $('.publishNewQuestion').slideUp();
    }

    // HANDLE ERRORS >>
    if(error) {$.bootstrapGrowl(error, {type: 'danger',offset: {from: 'bottom', amount: 20},align: 'right',width: 'auto',delay: 4000,allow_dismiss: true,stackup_spacing: 10});}


});
```

.
is there a workaround?
something i do to make ajax work in sub-domain?

Comment: Where is your `wp_ajax_action_submit_faq` defined? Is the ajax_object.ajaxurl generating the correct url?

Comment: the wp_ajax_action_submit_faq - is defined in the PHP file - ... it does work for main top / no sub-domain site. so... its the right url - but doesnt seem to be the right one when using multisite in a sub domain

Comment: Defined in which PHP file? And how are you creating the `ajax_object.ajaxurl`?

Comment: "ajax_object.ajaxurl" is a built in wordpress url - I would bounty this question tommarow - thanks for trying to help but you keep searching for what is broken - but this works for main site - just not for sub domain site - conclusion... this works, defines well, finds the PHP. I need a conditional (i think) / relative to sub domain "ajaxurl" or other solution.

Comment: I ask these questions because if it is in a plugin, are you sure the plugin is activated for 2nd site. If it is in functions.php, are you using the same theme for both sites?

Comment: ohh.. logical question and thanks for your time and effort. its in a theme.